# Cómo puedo deshabilitar un nodo en vis-network

Tags: javascript, vis-js

¿Me podrían ayudar a saber cómo se puede deshabilitar un nodo en vis network. Intenté con un `disabled`, pero no lo acepta.

Solo quiero que se muestren dos nodos activos y los demás desactivados, o bloqueados. Ya lo intenté, pero no se desactivan.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Network</title>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"
    ></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #mynetwork {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
      }
    </style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mynetwork"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // create an array with nodes
      var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
        { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
        { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
        { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
      ]);
 
      // create an array with edges
      var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        { from: 1, to: 3 },
        { from: 1, to: 2 },
        { from: 2, to: 4 },
        { from: 2, to: 5 },
        { from: 3, to: 3 },
      ]);
 
      // create a network
      var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
      var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges,
      };
      var options = {};
      var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Esta es la imagen de como se muestran actualmente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es al revés, `enabled: false`. Sin embargo, esta opción apunta a deshabilitar la interface de configuración de la red exclusivamente.

Hay varias opciones para jugar con la física, la mayoría dentro de la configuración de nodos, que te recomiendo leer: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html

Estas son las que me parecen más genéricas para tu caso, y las aplico al ejemplo:

- `fixed: true` (nodos 1 y 2 -no se mueven)
- `chosen: false` (nodo 2 -que no tenga efecto al seleccionar, también apliqué a edges)
- `color: 'algun-color'` (nodos 1 y 3 en gris)
- `hidden: true` (nodo 4 -no aparece)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Network</title>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"
    ></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #mynetwork {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
      }
    </style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mynetwork"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // create an array with nodes
      var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        { id: 1, label: "Node 1", fixed: true, color: 'gray' },
        { id: 2, label: "Node 2", fixed: true, chosen: false },
        { id: 3, label: "Node 3", color: 'rgb(200,200,200)'},
        { id: 4, label: "Node 4", hidden: true },
        { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
      ]);
 
      // create an array with edges
      var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        { from: 1, to: 3 },
        { from: 1, to: 2, chosen: false },
        { from: 2, to: 4, chosen: false },
        { from: 2, to: 5, chosen: false },
        { from: 3, to: 3 },
      ]);
 
      // create a network
      var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
      var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges,
      };
      var options = {};
      var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por lo que estás diciendo ahora, me imagino que te referís al efecto que tiene al seleccionar, con `chosen: false` ... recién edité la respuesta, fijate en nodo 2 (también habría que aplicar a los edges si querés el efecto ahí)

Comment: Probablemente sea un error y que lo hayas escrito en el lugar equivocado... Podés ver en lo que publiqué, haciendo click en `Ejecutar`, que se genera sin dar errores en consola

Comment: Publlicá el código completo como una **nueva** pregunta